# Setting character encoding in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, character-encoding, liferay

I'm trying to set the character encoding in a javax.portlet.PortletReqest object but this object doesn't seem to have a setCharacterEncoding() method that seems to be used in all examples I have come across including the Liferay site.
What it does have though, is a setAttribute() method where I can specify a key and a value so I assume I could set it there like setAttribute("characterEncoding", "UTF-8"); or something similar
I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of available attributes anywhere. I'm using Liferay 6.1
I'm trying to do this as I'm having problems displaying Spanish characters.

Comment: I figured it out. I have to get the HTTPServletRequest and set it there like so:
PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request).setCharacterEncoding("encoding");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense at a `PortletRequest`/`PortletResponse` to specify character encoding: `ActionRequest` (a subtype of `PortletRequest`) actually defines setCharacterEncoding, on `RenderRequest` it doesn't make any sense. Also, you're shielded from the `HttpServletRequest` for a reason: You typically don't know how much of it is already parsed when you are in a portlet.

You might have found something that works today for you on your current application server in the current version. Don't rely on it to continue to work in future. In fact, prepare for it to break in the least favorible moment.

I suggest you give us some insight into the underlying problem - why do you think that you need to mess around with the encoding? It might be as simple as a proper appserver configuration or other setting that you got wrong.

Comment: I'm having problem displaying Spanish characters. The characters are already incorrect in catalina.out. For example I get ¿½ or  � instead of ñ depending on if I set UTF-8 or Latin-1 in the <head>.
You are right by the way. request.setCharacterEncoding() doesn't work